# PHP / MYSQL Voting system for user blog/forum

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a blog/forum system which has upvotes/downvote and each comment can also have an upvote/downvote like the reddit/stackoverflow system.

Which is the best way to ensure that a user who has already upvoted can't upvote it again?

I did consider the possibility of making a new row with an seperate upvote table.But if a post has 30 comments then the script would end up doing 30 database queries which can also put a tremendous load on my server. Another possibility would be to make a row for each upvote of user,query them together and check with post_id which is again infeasible.

So which is the best way for upvote/downvote system and what do sites like stumbleupon/reddit do? As in the moment he log's in, the he can see a red color maybe to the posts he has already upvoted

Comment: What I would do is make a seperate database table and each post has a row, and each row has a column that stores an array of users who have voted. So basically if user 1,2,5 and 8 all voted, you can store that as [1,2,5,8] (stored as json, so you can `json_decode` it to use it later. 1 database call

Comment: "the script would end up doing 30 database queries" Why? If a user upvotes a specific comment, you only have to check that one comment to see if they voted on it before. It's one very simple SQL query to do that. You just need a votes table which joins to commentID in the comment table, and contains the UserID and whether it was an up/down vote. Then you do a query on the commentID/UserID combo. They're unlikely to try and vote on all 30, realistically. If you think that's a possibility then you need to design your system to scale sufficiently, and/or use powerful enough hardware.

Comment: *"Another possibility would be to make a row for each upvote of user,query them together and check with post_id which is again infeasible."* ... why is that infeasible? Sounds like a simple joining table to me with user id, question id (as a compound PRIMARY KEY probably) and vote recorded (+1 or -1 as a SIGNED TINYINT(2))

Comment: "But if a post has 30 comments then the script would end up doing 30 database queries" - implies that 1) you already have imposed a schema or are using a really horrible ORM and 2) your schema sucks.

Comment: @ADyson - Have you seen reddit? The moment you upvote it,even if you login the next time,you can see the posts you have already upvoted ..so for a hundred posts there then does it check if we have already upvoted it for 100 posts or not?

Comment: @user2990955 I can later put an example of query, if you need.

Comment: @user2990955 no, it doesn't, it does 1 query against the votes table, filtering by your username, and those votes are linked to posts by a foreign key, so it can pull down the posts details simultaneously in one go. 1 query with 100 results, not 100 queries. You're assuming you always have to filter by a single post (or comments in your case), but you can start from any perspective you want. They key is a correctly normalised database, and then you can find almost anything you want in a minimum number of queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the best way to do it is to make a separate table for up/down votes, where you save user's id and is it up or down vote, and include reputation to comments/posts/whatever table.

If a user tries to do up/down vote you only need to check one comment (why 30?). Then you simply check in the separate table if the user has already voted for that comment/post. If so, you can remove vote (for example like in SO – if you press up vote twice, your upvote will be removed), or if person pressed a different button (f.e. downvote after upvote) you can just change his vote. The reason why I offered you to add reputation column to your posts/comments table and update it after all up,down votes is that then you will not need to get `count(*)` of reputation from that separate table and your comment/post reputation will be easy and fast to recieve, especially, if your database has many rows.

Comment: Thanks,but how does the user see if he has already upvoted it before....as in the moment he log's in, the he can see a red color maybe to the posts he has already upvoted,i was talking about that type of a system

Comment: @user2990955 well, i believe then when getting the comments you can use **LEFT JOIN** and get votes `WHERE posts.post_id=YourPostID and reputation_giver=loggedUsersId` and then you either get that logged in users up/down votes or get null if the user had not voted yet. You can see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left), where null is returned - customer has no oders.